# oninput and onchange not working because of bad coding

Tags: javascript, html

My code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBuys1290/nyomkv3x/23/). Below is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Electricity and Magnetism Demo</title>

<body>
<p>
  <label>Voltage:</label>
  <input id="inputVoltage" type="number" oninput="EqualsVoltage()" onchange="EqualsVoltage()"> </p>

<p>
  <label>Current:</label>
  <input id="inputCurrent" type="number" oninput="EqualsCurrent()" onchange="EqualsCurrent()"> </p>

<p>
  <label>Resistance:</label>
  <input id="inputResistance" type="number" oninput="EqualsResistance()" onchange="EqualsResistance()"> </p>
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="EandM.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
//Electricity and Magnetism Stuff

function EqualsVoltage() {

    var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
    var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
    var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;

    document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value = (Current * Resistance);

}

function EqualsCurrent() {

    var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
    var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
    var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;

    document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value = (Voltage / Resistance);

}

function EqualsResistance() {

    var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
    var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
    var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;

    document.getElementById("inputResistance").value = (Voltage / Current);

}
```

I want my calculator to react to both oninput and onchange events when I change a value in the text field.

I've been able to make a converter that converts kilometers to miles when `oninput` and `onchange` were functioning; however, I can't figure this out.

When I enter data in the field, it doesn't change the other values. Please help!

Comment: no need to pass arguments to functions that don't do anything with the arguments

Comment: Just a semantic observation -- the L in some of your `getElementById` are capitalized. Obviously they should not be.

Comment: you're also calling "changeVoltage" when you input voltage, therefore, any new value in voltage will be overwritten by calling changeVoltage ... changeVoltage should calculate the OTHER TWO variables (not sure how you can do that, since a change in voltage will result in either a change in current or a change in resistance or both)

Comment: This site has some nice simple examples of what you are trying to accomplish. Have a look --- https://www.javascriptbank.com/ohm-law-calculator.html

Comment: Revised the code.

Comment: Take a look at my answer for a fully working answer, Using the code you supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. Should have been checking the other text boxes not the current one. It will keep changing the fields as the user increases or decreases the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Electricity and Magnetism Demo</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function EqualsVoltage() {

                var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
                var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
                var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;
                if(Resistance != "0" && Current != "0" ){
                      document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value = (Current * Resistance);
                }


            }

           function EqualsCurrent() {

                var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
                var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
                var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;
                if(Voltage != "0" && Resistance != "0" ){
                    document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value = (Voltage / Resistance);
                }
            }

            function EqualsResistance() {

                var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
                var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
                var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;

                if(Voltage != "0" && Current != "0" ){
                    document.getElementById("inputResistance").value = (Voltage / Current);
                }

           }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <p>
          <label>Voltage:</label>
         <input id="inputVoltage" type="number" oninput="EqualsResistance(); EqualsCurrent()" value="0"> </p>

     <p>
        <label>Current:</label>
        <input id="inputCurrent" type="number" oninput="EqualsVoltage(); EqualsResistance()" value="0"> </p>

     <p>
       <label>Resistance:</label>
        <input id="inputResistance" type="number" oninput="EqualsCurrent();EqualsVoltage()" value="0"> </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem: when user edit e.g. voltage in input then calculations at the same time change that input value (the input values and calculated values are usually different). Solution: show output calculations in separate place - not as input values. When you use `oninput` you don't need to use `onchange`.

```js
function calc() {
  let c = inputCurrent.value;
  let r = inputResistance.value;
  let v = inputVoltage.value;

  msg.innerHTML = `voltage:    ${ c*r } <br>`
                + `current:    ${ v/r } <br>`
                + `resistance: ${ v/c } <br>`;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Voltage:</label>
  <input id="inputVoltage" type="number" oninput="calc()">
</p>

<p>
  <label>Current:</label>
  <input id="inputCurrent" type="number" oninput="calc()"> 
</p>

<p>
  <label>Resistance:</label>
  <input id="inputResistance" type="number" oninput="calc()"> 
</p>

Calculations:
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a great answer you can take, but I wanted to provide you an alternative. It's up to you which one fits better to your needs.

This solution provides an alternative for the user to decide when to calculate the values. This can avoid unexpected values as Infinity, 0, etc..

For this, you could give a button to every element in order to let the user click the one he wants the result for. This will update the value to the input box where he presses the button. The button would look like this:

```
    <p>
     <label>Resistance:</label>
     <input id="inputResistance" type="number"> 
     <button id="calcResistance"><!-- Add this to every input -->
       Calc
     </button>
    </p>
```

And your JavaScript code will look like this:

```
function updateValues(e) {
    let changed = e.target.id,
        Voltage = Number(document.getElementById('inputVoltage').value),
        Current = Number(document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value),
        Resistance = Number(document.getElementById('inputResistance').value);

      switch(changed){
      case "calcResistance":
        document.getElementById("inputResistance").value = (Voltage / Current);
      break;

      case "calcVoltage":
        document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value = (Current * Resistance);
      break;

      case "calcCurrent":
        document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value = Voltage / Resistance;
      break;
    }

}

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b=>b.addEventListener("click",updateValues));
```

I hope this gives you another way to achieve what you want.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0r3s8uw2/) of what I am talking about:

```js
function updateValues(e) {
 let changed = e.target.id,
     Voltage = Number(document.getElementById('inputVoltage').value),
    Current = Number(document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value),
    Resistance = Number(document.getElementById('inputResistance').value);
 
   switch(changed){
      case "calcResistance":
        document.getElementById("inputResistance").value = (Voltage / Current);
      break;

      case "calcVoltage":
        document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value = (Current * Resistance);
      break;

      case "calcCurrent":
        document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value = Voltage / Resistance;
      break;
   }

}

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b=>b.addEventListener("click",updateValues));
```

```html
<p>
    <label>Voltage:</label>
    <input id="inputVoltage" type="number"> 
    <button id="calcVoltage">
      Calc
    </button></p>

    <p>
    <label>Current:</label>
    <input id="inputCurrent" type="number"> 
    <button id="calcCurrent">
      Calc
    </button></p>

    <p>
    <label>Resistance:</label>
    <input id="inputResistance" type="number"> 
    <button id="calcResistance">
      Calc
    </button></p>
```

Comment: Very nice idea to change "direction" of UX : not change value after input change, but set value after button click (which seem to be more "natural": first we type values on eg. resistance and current and then push button on voltage to calc its value) +1

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `onkeyup` instead of `onchange` and `oninput`. [edit] Wont work with the buttons, however.

---

I'm guessing the workflow is "When I enter something two number fields, the third one is calculated".

But what happens then if all three text fields are filled in?

If you filled in voltage, current, and resistance, and then change voltage again, should current or resistance change?

You need to think about workflow *before* you do any coding, and that's why the code is wrong.

Comment: Please do comment if you vote something down. The answer I made is basically talking about doing the foundations of programming right, not providing a finished code. I would had done that, unless I had stepped into this  flaw in thinking in this assignment.

Comment: Would using the buttons on the field cause a keyup event? Further, when changing the fields with oninput event,  the fields change as the user inputs, a case that "all the fields were changed at the same time" would be irrelevant?

Comment: Good one about the buttons. I didn't think of that. Regarding fields changing at the same time, that's not what I meant, but I can't explain it better than I actually did. If _voltage_ is changed, then _current_ and _resistance_ cannot change at the same time, because _current_ is depending on _resistance_, and _resistance_ on _current_. Either _current_ or _resistance_ must remain static.

Comment: What's that idea of using `onkeyup` here? Why not `onmousemove` when you're at it? Or even `setTimeout(fn, Math.random() * Infinity)`? It will not only fail with the buttons, but with right-click + paste, with assistive devices, will fire unnecessarily on shift press etc.

Comment: ah, I understand. yes this was my issue when coming up with a solution. I covered this as well. +1